# Rails link_to with default HTML button style

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Rails form that has a submit button using a FormHelper.

```
<p><%= form.submit %></p>
```

On the same page, I have a cancel button that goes back to the previous page (the index page).

```
<p><%= link_to 'Cancel', base_files_path() %></p>
```

I want to style my `link_to` element so that it looks like the submit button. I tried the `button_to` FormHelper but it creates its own submit button, which is interfering with the normal form's submit operation. Is there a class that I can attach to the `link_to` element that will style it like that?

[Here is a screenshot for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTQsY.png)

Comment: are you using Bootstrap in your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*EDIT*: I want to add that it is possible to use the `button_to` helper, and it works like `link_to`, but only when you aren't working with a form, because then the `button_to` form will raise conflicts. This was an issue for me because the cancel button was triggering form validation on my form.

AFAIK this isn't possible to do with any built-in Rails components, so instead I opted to use HTML and Javascript to get what I wanted.

Old code:

```
<%= link_to 'Cancel', base_files_path() %>
```

New code:

```
<button type='button' onclick="location.href='<%= base_files_path() %>';">Cancel</button>
```

The code isn't pretty, but it's the quickest way for me to get the look I was going for.

Comment: Why do you use one of the helpers like `button`, `button_tag` or `button_to` (depending on your needs)?

Comment: @spickermann Hi, please see my addendum relating to your comment in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Styling is the job of CSS. You might want to “tag” your link with a CSS class name and reference it from a stylesheet:

```
link_to 'Cancel', base_fules_path, class: "button"

.button {
  /* your styles here */
}
```

Native styles are dependent on the platform. You can use `appearance: button` styles on your link, but [`appearance` isn't particularly well supported](https://caniuse.com/#search=appearance).

Comment: I want to get the appearance of an `<input type='button'>` element. Is that possible to do with the `link_to` FormHelper? I would rather not write my own styles for a button since I am perfectly content with the look of the submit button created by Rails. Looking at the [documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to), those buttons have the `form_class` of `button_to`. Using that class on my `link_to` element does nothing. Where can I peruse the default styles that Rails uses?

Comment: @Fam Rails isn't styling those buttons. Those are naked `<input type="submit">` elements, which browsers tend to render similar to `<button>` elements. Again, you can use `appearance: button` to get this effect, which is what I suggested 2 hours ago.

Comment: I tried using `appearance` and it gets me halfway there, but the button text is using the wrong font. I ended up using a button element that uses an `onclick` event handler.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap with your project, you can get the same format by:

```
<%= link_to 'Cancel', base_files_path,class: "btn btn-default" %>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to add the class option

```
<p><%= link_to 'Cancel', base_files_path(), class: "your_class_here" %></p>
```

Comment: Adding classes isn't the problem, knowing what class to add is.